# Is there a way to get bouncy cursor using Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, cursor

I have just realized that compiz doesn't have the option for a [bouncing cursor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQD2xR6ZQAI&feature=youtu.be&t=15s) (a cursor that will bounce whenever you access an application, like a busy cursor) as KDE does it.

Is there a way to enable (or get) such a feature?